# Trying to precompile html files in to one js file using grunt/gulp

Tags: javascript, node.js, templates, gruntjs, grunt-template-module

In my Single page application project, I am using client templates. After searching on Internet, I came to know that client side templates can be organized in three ways:

- Writing Script tags in index.html with type, say: `text/template`.
- Writing the templates in separate `.html` files and write the code in server to gather all the `.html` files and create one `.js` file.
- Watching changes in template on client side: In this there will be a compiler which watches the `.html` template files for changes and generates/updates a  `.js` file.  (*just like SCSS or less*)

The first approach is making my `index.html` look messed up. So, I decided to go with the third approach because it keeps client side code to itself without any interference from sever code (*like second approach*).

I am using `Backbone` and `lodash.js` for templates.

I found that I can watch the templates for changes using `grunt`'s [`grunt-template-module`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-template-module).

I have gone through getting started of grunt and added `Gruntfile.js` and `package.json` in the root folder of my project.

#### Gruntfile.js

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    // Project configuration.
    grunt.initConfig({
        template-module: {
            myTemplates:{
                files: {
                    "demo.js": ["app/templates/header.html"]
                }
                options: {
                    module: true
                }
            }
        }
    });
};
```

#### package.json

```
// empty file
```

Now, I am not able to understand what should I do next? Any help would be really appreciated?

**PS**: The backend technology is **PHP**. I am using node.js just to access grunt. Please also let me know if there is any better alternative.